# Trouble with Box Sizers in WxPython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I've been trying to produce something that allows me to have multiple sentences in a line.
The code is:

```
import wx
app = wx.PySimpleApp()


class MyDialog(wx.Frame):
"""
This is my dialog in which I have my interface.
"""
def __init__(self):
    """
    This stores all my variables.
    """
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Edit Action", size=(400, 300))
    self.my_mini_panels = []
    self.my_mini_hboxes = []
    self.my_mini_vboxes = []
    self.main_vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.main_hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.my_mini_panels.append(wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER,
                                        size=(400, 20)))
    self.my_mini_hboxes.append(wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL))
    self.my_mini_vboxes.append(wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL))
    self.my_mini_hboxes[0].AddMany((wx.StaticText(self.my_mini_panels[0],
                                                  -1, 'Here it is... '),
                                    wx.StaticText(self.my_mini_panels[0],
                                                  -1, 'There it was.')))
    self.my_mini_panels.append(wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER,
                                        size=(400, 20)))
    self.my_mini_hboxes.append(wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL))
    self.my_mini_vboxes.append(wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL))
    self.my_mini_hboxes[1].AddMany((wx.StaticText(self.my_mini_panels[1],
                                                  -1, 'Hello, '),
                                    wx.StaticText(self.my_mini_panels[1],
                                                  -1, 'Goodbye!')))
    for i, hbox in enumerate(self.my_mini_hboxes):
        hbox.Add(self.my_mini_vboxes[i])
    self.main_vbox.AddMany(tuple(self.my_mini_hboxes))
    self.main_hbox.Add(self.main_vbox)
    self.SetSizer(self.main_hbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
dialog = MyDialog()
dialog.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

It doesn't seem to be working. I'd like it to look like this:[image]

What am I doing wrong?

## EDIT

Perhaps I should make it clear that the static text objects **must** be separate. I can't just replace two segments of text on one line with one larger segment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need lots of sizers and panels for this. You can use one panel + one sizer + two static text widgets. Here's the code:

```
import wx

class MyDialog(wx.Frame):
    """
    This is my dialog in which I have my interface.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        This stores all my variables.
        """
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Edit Action", size=(400, 300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        main_vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        label_one = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Here it is... There it was.")
        label_two = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Hello, Goodbye!")

        main_vbox.Add(label_one, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        main_vbox.Add(label_two, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        panel.SetSizer(main_vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    dialog = MyDialog()
    dialog.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note also that I changed your app object from wx.PySimpleApp to just wx.App. The wx.PySimpleApp has been deprecated and it is recommended to use wx.App from now on.

You might consider sub-classing from wx.Dialog instead of wx.Frame as that would make more sense if this is really supposed to be a dialog.